# Olingo returns DateTime or Timestamp values in a wrong format

Tags: spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa, sapui5, olingo

I made an odata service with Olingo2/JPA and spring-boot based on this [GitHub repository](https://github.com/jpenninkhof/odata-boilerplate).

The problem is olingo does not return the date/time or timestamp columns in a correct format as defined in Odata standard (or maybe Microsoft standard). I mean my front-end library (i.e. OpenUI5) expects some value like `<d:ValidFrom>/Date(1579075200000)/</d:ValidFrom>` for `Edm.DateTime` column but what olingo returns is `<d:ValidFrom>2020-01-15T08:00:00</d:ValidFrom>` which is not accepted by OpenUI5!

What is your suggestion?

1- Is there a way that I force Olingo to return data/time or timestamp in the format that Microsoft defined or not? (i.e. `/Date(timestamp)/`)

2- Is there a way that OpenUI5 accept the date\time in a format like `yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss` ?

Comment: I just tested one of our SAP services. When returning XML it uses the format `<d:Budat>2017-02-23T00:00:00</d:Budat>`. When returning JSON it uses the format `Budat: "/Date(1487808000000)/"`. It's an `Edm.DateTime` with `Precision="7"`.

Comment: Hi Marc. You where correct I needed to pass `$format=json` to get the correct value. You can write it as the answer and I will accept.

Comment: Well it should work in both formats. XML is the default in UI5 and as I stated, UI5 should be able to parse `2017-02-23T00:00:00`.

Comment: Yes you are right. I stored the result in a json file for using in mockserver and that only accept the timestamps!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I discussed with @Marc in the comments, `olingo` in `XML` format returns the `data\time` or `timestamp` columns in the format of `yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss`:

[image: date format in odata via xml]

as soon as we request the output in the `JSON` format by passing `?$format=json` in the URL, the `data\time` values will be return in the format of timestamp, while the value is enclosed by `/Date()` string to show it is a `data/time` value. (This standard is defined by Microsoft!)

[image: date format in odata via json]

In `UI5` if you are going to store the data for feeding to your mock server it is needed to store the data in `JSON` file and obviously the `date\time` values must be stored like `/Date(timestamp)`.

Answer (score 0):

In this case you need to create in JPA the field like:

```
@Column(name="dClas")
private Timestamp dClas;
```

And than translate the JavaType Timestamp to respective EdmType DateTimeOffset:

```
public static EdmPrimitiveTypeKind getEdmPrimitiveTypeFor(Class<?> clazz) throws RuntimeException {
    EdmPrimitiveTypeKind result = types.get(clazz);
    if (result == null) {
        Optional<Class<?>> potentialType = types.keySet().stream().filter(javaClass -> javaClass.isAssignableFrom(clazz)).findFirst();
        if (potentialType.isPresent()) {
            result = types.get(potentialType.get());
        } else {
            throw new RuntimeException("Property of type " + clazz + " cannot be mapped to OData type");
        }
    }

    return result;
}

private static final Map<Class<?>, EdmPrimitiveTypeKind> types = new HashMap<>() {{
    put(String.class, EdmPrimitiveTypeKind.String);
    put(Integer.class, EdmPrimitiveTypeKind.Int32);
    put(Integer.TYPE, EdmPrimitiveTypeKind.Int32);
    put(Long.class, EdmPrimitiveTypeKind.Int64);
    put(Long.TYPE, EdmPrimitiveTypeKind.Int64);
    put(Double.class, EdmPrimitiveTypeKind.Double);
    put(Double.TYPE, EdmPrimitiveTypeKind.Double);
    put(Boolean.class, EdmPrimitiveTypeKind.Boolean);
    put(Boolean.TYPE, EdmPrimitiveTypeKind.Boolean);
    put(Float.class, EdmPrimitiveTypeKind.Single);
    put(Float.TYPE, EdmPrimitiveTypeKind.Single);
    put(Short.class, EdmPrimitiveTypeKind.Int16);
    put(Short.TYPE, EdmPrimitiveTypeKind.Int16);
    //put(BigDecimal.class, EdmPrimitiveTypeKind.Decimal);
    put(BigDecimal.class, EdmPrimitiveTypeKind.Double);
    put(Calendar.class, EdmPrimitiveTypeKind.Date);
    put(Date.class, EdmPrimitiveTypeKind.Date);
    put(LocalDate.class, EdmPrimitiveTypeKind.Date);
    put(Timestamp.class, EdmPrimitiveTypeKind.DateTimeOffset);
    put(LocalDateTime.class, EdmPrimitiveTypeKind.DateTimeOffset);
    put(byte[].class, EdmPrimitiveTypeKind.Binary);
    put(Byte[].class, EdmPrimitiveTypeKind.Binary);
    put(Blob.class, EdmPrimitiveTypeKind.Binary);
    put(Byte.class, EdmPrimitiveTypeKind.SByte);
    put(Byte.TYPE, EdmPrimitiveTypeKind.SByte);
    put(LocalTime.class, EdmPrimitiveTypeKind.TimeOfDay);
    put(Time.class, EdmPrimitiveTypeKind.TimeOfDay);
    put(Duration.class, EdmPrimitiveTypeKind.Duration);
    put(UUID.class, EdmPrimitiveTypeKind.Guid);
    put(Clob.class, EdmPrimitiveTypeKind.String);
}};
```

The translation need to happens when you design the Olingo OData MetaData.